# Return the original value if there is a null in the computation

Tags: mysql, database, join, coalesce

I'm having trouble with my query in getting only the original value if its computing a null value from another type. I'm computing those original values according to type 5 minus to typeid 10.

Please take note that my data structure and my data types are all over the place and will be hard to read for new users. In order to determine the value, you have to focus on type and typeid.

The type that I get in getting the original value for the discounts is 5

Here are the query and original values:

Query:

```
select a.ID as `ID`, a.DOB as `DATE`, a.AMOUNT as `TOTAL`, (SELECT 
coalesce(sum(case when gndsale.type= "5" then gndsale.amount end), 0) from 
gndsale where gndsale.ID = b.ID and gndsale.DOB = a.DOB having 
sum(gndsale.type = "5") > 0 ) as `DISCOUNTS` FROM gndsale a 
INNER JOIN emp b ON a.ID = b.ID  
WHERE a.type = "22" and STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-05-01' 
AND '2017-05-31' GROUP BY TOTAL order by STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

I have a  **typeid of 10**  that will determine another discount which is senior

Here are the query and the values of senior

Query:

```
select a.ID as `ID`, a.DOB as `DATE`, a.AMOUNT as `TOTAL`, (SELECT 
coalesce(sum(case when gndsale.typeid= "10" then gndsale.amount end), 0) from 
gndsale where gndsale.ID= b.ID and gndsale.DOB = a.DOB having 
sum(gndsale.typeid = "10") > 0 ) as `DISCOUNTS` FROM gndsale a 
INNER JOIN emp b ON a.ID= b.ID  
WHERE a.type = "22" and STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-05-01' 
AND '2017-05-31' GROUP BY TOTAL order by STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

I have a null value with my Senior Discount.

What I want to do is I want to minus the original Discounts value and the Senior Discounts value which means I have to minus the value that has a  **type = 5 and a typeid = 10** . Fortunately, I was able to compute and I got my result

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM**  I have a null value on my expected result. The problem is because its computing a null value from the  **Senior result** what I want is that the null value should return only the Original Discount Value if its computing null values.

Here's my query:

```
select a.ID as `ID`, a.DOB as `DATE`, a.AMOUNT as `TOTAL`, (SELECT 
coalesce(sum(case when gndsale.type= "5" then gndsale.amount end), 0) - 
coalesce(sum(case when gndsale.TYPEID= "10" then gndsale.amount end), 0) END 
from gndsale where gndsale.ID= b.ID and gndsale.DOB = a.DOB having 
sum(gndsale.type = "5") > 0 and sum(gndsale.TYPEID= "10") > 0 ) as `OTHER 
DISCOUNT` FROM gndsale a INNER JOIN emp b ON a.ID= b.ID WHERE a.type 
= "22" and STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-
31' GROUP BY TOTAL order by STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Note:  **THEY ARE BASED ON THE DATES**  and I can't post pictures yet.. My current result I'm having is on the Other Discount.

Comment: This isn't a very good question.  Please _show_ us a minimal sample of data, and then show us the output you want.  The sooner you clean up your query, the better off you will be later on when it really matters.

Comment: Consider adding a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), in addition to keeping the important info in your question. That will allow you to supply a table structure, some test data and a query that does not work as you expect.